# Error in conditional statement using list

Tags: python, loops, arraylist, syntax-error, push

```
a=[]
for i in range(0,6):
  mark=int(input("enter the mark")
  if len(a)==0:
    a.insert(0,mark):
  else:
    a.insert(len(a)-1,mark)
  

b=sum(a)/5
print(b)
```

That's the code I've been getting errors in

I expected the output to ask for the mark
in loop and give me the average

Comment: `mark=int(input("enter the mark")` That line is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: You also need to remove the colon (:) at the end of this line: `a.insert(0,mark):`

Comment: And you ask for `6` marks in that `for-loop` : so you should be dividing by 6 in this line: `b=sum(a)/5`

Comment: Please post the errors you are getting. A full traceback is best. You have syntax errors, I assume that's the error you see?

Answer (score 0):

Only a couple of **minor fixes** required:

```
a=[]
for i in range(0,6):
  mark=int(input("enter the mark"))
  if len(a)==0:
    a.insert(0,mark)
  else:
    a.insert(len(a)-1,mark)
  

b=sum(a)/6
print(b)
```

### Note:

If they do not enter a number, you will get a **value error**, because of your line:

```
mark=int(input("enter the mark"))
```

In the line above, it will try to convert any number, letter etc to an **int**. If they enter a letter, it will not be able to do the conversion, and the program will **fail**.